# Rpm Package with multiple rpm-spec-files

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have heard that it is possible to use several rpm spec files in one package. Does any one know how?

My problem to solve: I would like to produce a set of rpms, which are all built alike but package a different version of a specific application.

So I would like to specify a list of versions, e.g. A1, A2, B1, B5... and for each version fetch a tar-ball with binaries and package them in an rpm "myapplication-A1.rpm", "myapplication-A2.rpm" ...

Either I can specify the versions as a simple list somewhere, or I could live with having to copy and modify a template spec file for each version.

When I build the (main) package all rpms should be built.

The feature of "rpm sub-package" by repeating %files, %build etc. sections in the spec file seems not to be the right tool for this.

My platform is Linux (CentOS7).

Comment: why `rpm sub-package` is _not_ right for this ? Show us what you have done in terms of coding. `%package -n %{name}-A1`, `%package -n %{name}-A2` will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Well I thougt that I would have to duplicate all rules etc. for each package. I give it a try tomorrow, maybe I can reduce this using macros. I would rather write the code once and then call it repeatedly using a variable.

Comment: You can put the repeating parts into a `%global`. You can also have variables come in and then a script or `Makefile` use the `--define` option on the command line.